# speedtest-CLI でProxy 経由での接続ができない

Tags: python, python3, windows-10

社内からSpeedテストを実行したいのですが、Proxyを経由させる必要があるため、
下記の通りProxyを設定したのですが、通信ができていないようです。
設定箇所、設定方法はあっているのでしょうか？

一応、コマンドプロンプトで、 netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie の設定は行っております。

```
import csv
import os
import datetime
import speedtest


def get_Speed_File(speedData):
    f_name = 'Home-SpeedTest.csv'
    date_str , time_str, mbps_down_result, mbps_up_result = speedData
    # SpeedTest.csvが存在する場合は、結果を追記
    if (os.path.exists(f_name)):
        with open(f_name, 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([date_str, time_str, mbps_down_result, mbps_up_result])
    else:
「Upload速度」
        with open(f_name, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
            filednames = ['Date', 'Time', 'Download(Mbps)', 'UPload(Mbps)']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=filednames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'Date': date_str, 'Time': time_str, 'Download(Mbps)': mbps_down_result, 'UPload(Mbps)':mbps_up_result })


def get_speed_test():
    os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://xxx.co.jp:8080"
    os.environ["https_proxy"] = "http://xxx.co.jp:8080"
    servers = []
    stest = speedtest.Speedtest()
    stest.get_servers(servers)
    stest.get_best_server()
    return stest


def command_line_runner():

    tmp_day = datetime.date.today()
    tmp_time = datetime.datetime.today()
    date_str = tmp_day.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    time_str = tmp_time.strftime('%H:%M')

    stest = get_speed_test()
    down_result = stest.download()
    up_result = stest.upload()
    mbps_down_result = int(down_result / 1024 /1024)
    mbps_up_result = int(up_result / 1024 /1024)


    result = [date_str, time_str, mbps_down_result, mbps_up_result]


    get_Speed_File(result)

    print(result)

command_line_runner()
```

Comment: 企業のproxyだと認証が必要とかでは？ [pythonのrequestsモジュールで認証プロキシを超えたい](https://qiita.com/shnchr/items/bbecc7cf984bf80aee27), [認証が必要なHTTPプロキシ環境下でpipコマンドを使う](https://qiita.com/wararaki/items/df537718be0f27171cdd) あとは「通信ができていないようです。」と判断した状況の詳細を追記した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 認証は行っておりません。「通信ができないようです。」については、上記コードをProxy環境外で実行すると、VSコードでデバッグを行うと、コールスタックに各サーバーに通信を行っている状況が発生しております。しかし、Proxy環境で上記コードを実行すると、コールスタックは、何も動作しておりません。

Comment: 例えばコマンドプロンプトの手作業で同等の操作(環境変数を設定してexe実行)を行った場合にどうなるかとか、VSCode等でステップ実行が出来るなら何処まで正常に動作しているか調べてみるとか、試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 私の環境(プロキシ経由)でもspeedtest-cli単体で応答が返ってきません。環境変数に設定したプロキシは効いています(straceで確認)。プロキシサーバが応答を返す外部サーバからのレスポンスをブロックしているようでした。プロキシサーバの設定によってはspeedtest-cliは使えないのかもしれません。

Comment: 先立って行われた関連ポスト？ [Python（speedtest-cli） Proxy環境下での実行方法について](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13247260128)

Comment: 手元の環境(Ubuntu Linux/tinyproxy)で試した限りではプロキシサーバ経由でも問題なく動作しています。日本サイトですと `best server` は `http://speed.coe.ad.jp:8080/` になるかと思いますが、この URL がそちらのプロキシサーバにブロック対象として登録されているのかもしれません(コンテンツフィルタリング)。